# Resuming ddrescue always restarts at first retry?

Tags: ddrescue

I'm using `ddrescue` to make an image of a faulty harddrive. I followed a tutorial that used the `-r3` and `logfile` option.

After a few hours, the tool made one pass and tried to read the bad sectors on the second. I had to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> because I went sleeping and didn't want to leave the computer running.

Now whenever I resume, `ddrescue` restarts at the first pass instead of the second. Is that normal? Can I assume that the image is done and the tool just tries to save some of the bad sectors listed in the logfile?

Comment: Are you sure anything has been recovered? Are you looking at the logfile for which blocks `ddrescue` is working on?

Comment: ddrescue said something about being finished with the first pass and going on retrying the faulty sectors. My guess is that the image is done with what could be saved from the faulty drive and now just retries to get the faulty sectors?

Comment: Yes it normally does so, but from the log, you can see which parts it is (re) trying and what it already recovered.